# What is wrong with this proof that anti-commutative matrices have product zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, fake-proofs

Suppose $AB-BA=0$, where $A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ matrices. Then $AB=-BA$. Then
\begin{aligned}
AB=\frac{1}{2}(AB+AB)=\frac{1}{2}(AB-BA)=\frac{1}{2}(0)=0.
\end{aligned}
I can't seem to find the error in this argument, although I know it's wrong because I found a counterexample by google search.

Comment: If you have $AB-BA=0$, then $A$ and $B$ commute. If $A$ and $B$ anti-commute, you have $AB+BA=0$.

Comment: @MatheiBoulomenos Thanks, of course I flipped signs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$AB-BA=0$ gives $AB=BA$, not $AB=-BA$. The $-BA$ term should change sign when you move it across the $=$.